# Relativistic Resistors

Tags: relativity, classical-electrodynamics

I would like to simulate what happens if you move electric circuits at relativistic speeds. At first, I would like to check the resistor.

If I move a wire in the simplest case with speed $v$ along its axis $\vec{e_z}$, I get as transformation the following expression $R' = \frac{l'}{\sigma'A} = \frac{l'm'}{e^2n'\tau'A}$ where $\sigma$ is the conductivity depending on mass, charge, spatial density and relaxation time $\tau$.

Inserting the correct transformations for mass, length, density and time I would expect $R' = R$. But it seems to me that the relaxation time is not a time transformed as usual.

Has anyone an idea how to deal with it? Otherwise, if I transform Ohm's law directly, it gets much more complicated due to the transformation of the relative speed of the electrons.

Comment: This topic has fascinated me for years. See my question on this site on how relativistic velocities affect inductors and capacitors (sorry I do not know how to tag it but will if I can figure it out). after the 2-day waiting period, I'll put a bounty on your question to encourage the community to furnish a good answer if no one responds by then. Regards, Niels

Comment: here's the link - https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/433230/what-is-the-behavior-of-an-electronic-oscillator-at-relativistic-speeds?s=1|27.1630